# Are "atmen" and "Atmosphäre" etymologically related?

Tags: etymology

While it feels like *atmen* ([Proto-Indo-European origin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/%C4%93%C3%BEmaz)) and *Atmosphäre* ([Greek origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere)) should be etymologically related - I couldn't find any proof for this. Are they?...

Comment: DWDS says they aren't: [_atmen_](https://www.dwds.de/wb/atmen) [_Atmosphäre_](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Atmosph%C3%A4re)

Comment: Doesn't _Greek_ also count to have a _Proto-Indo-European_ origin?

Comment: If Greek also has Proto-Indo-European origin so the both roots can theoretically be traced back to a common ancestor, can't they?

Comment: Well, DWDS says: _"griech. atmós (ἀτμός) ‘Dunst, Dampf’"_ (moist, mist, haze, steam), while _atmen_ stems from _"aind. ātmā́ ‘Hauch, Seele, Selbst’ (Stamm ātmán-)"_ (breath, breeze, soul, self). In a less direct way these may have a common root, yes. But IMO hard to get a proof.

Comment: Does someone has access to an etymological dictionary of ancient greek, for instance https://dictionaries.brillonline.com/search#dictionary=greek&id=gr0920 ? This might bring some light into the question whether _ἀτμός_ stems from the same indoeuropean root.

Answer (score 6):

The modern Verb *»atmen«* was Middle High German (MHG) *»atemen«* and Old High German (OHG) (10<sup>th</sup> century) *»atamon«.* It is derived from the noun *»Atem«* (MHG *»atem«,* OHG *»atum«*). Etymologist believe, that the closest form in other old languages is Old Indian *»atma«* or *»atman«* which means *breath, breeze, mind, soul, the self.*

The word *»Atmosphäre«* was brought into German language as a foreign word used by scientists in the 17<sup>th</sup> century as a composition of the greek words

- ἀτμός (atmós) = steam, vapor, mist, haze, breath, breeze
- σφαῖρα (sphaira) = ball, sphere

The first of the two words is closely related to the verb ἄημι (áēmi) which means *"to breath, to blow"* and both are derived from Proto Indo European *»áwēmi«.* This again is also the root of English and German noun *»Wind«* and from latin *»ventus«* (which means *wind* and can be found in German *»Ventilator«* but also *»Ventil«*)

In my researches I did not find a clear statement that says, that Old Indian *»atma«* is related to greek *»atmós«* (both can mean *breath, breeze*) or to Proto Indo European *»áwēmi«.* But since the meaning of these words is so similar, and also the words themselves sound so similar, I believe, that there is a connection. But, as just said: I didn't find any clear statements about such a relationship.

Comment: What are the modern and ancient Greek words for "breath"? I mean with major meaning...

Comment: I don't have a dictionary at hand, but I think that would be _pneuma_.

Comment: @user1876484: Google translator says: "breath" = αναπνοή (anapnoi) (modern greek). There also is an English wikipedia article about [Breathing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breathing) and the title of the greek version is [Αναπνοή (Anapnoi)](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/Αναπνοή). Wiktionary says, that ancient greek πνεῦμα (pneuma) means *air, wind, breath, life, spirit, soul* and the equivalent verb is πνέω (pnéō, “I blow”).